# OOP Design Pattern / reading information from file or API?

Tags: matlab, oop, design-patterns

I have (x2) ways to get information for my object:

1. Read from a file stored on the disc
2. Access the application that made the file through the application's API

Once the information is acquired, I'll have methods to:

- Display
- Analyze
- Change the information (again as either a file or through the API)

If I change the information, it need not be the same way that I received the information.  Therefore I could:

- Receive the info by file and push the info back by API
- and all the other obvious combinations...

I won't have additional ways to get the data in/out (e.g. API and file cover all options).

The code will be in Matlab, so I don't have easy access to enumerated types and a few other nice programming features, so I'm tempted to use a design pattern rather than a *switch* inside the class.

**Questions**

What are appropriate design patterns for this problem?

Should I use a design pattern and write a few classes to get this done or just write a single class with a *switch* for *file* or *API*?

Comment: This is the best one: *"and all the other obvious combinations..."* . . . . *"What are appropriate design patterns for this problem?"*  -  Each design pattern comes with the description of the problem it tries to solve. . .  . *"Should I use a design pattern"* - you can do anything you want. This is totally up to you

Comment: Yeah... I looked through the GoF Design Patterns.  Didn't quite understand how to map one to my problem.  I know I can do whatever I want.  My hope was that experience (which is what made Design Patterns in the first place) would guide me to a better solution.  That's why I asked for advice.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are generally not well-treated here. sourcemaking.com

Answer (score 2):

One logical way to allow multiple forms for reading data is to have multiple forms of the constructor (or a `read` method):

```
classdef DataObject
   %...
   methods
      function obj = DataObject(fname)
         if nargin==1
            % read data from file fname
            %...
         else
            % read data through an API
            %...
         end
      end
   end
end
```

You can do

```
obj1 = DataObject;                 % Reads through API
obj2 = DataObject('somefile.txt'); % Reads from file
```

A similar thing could apply to a `write` method.